# How to re-direct to a page using button in drop down list(options_for_select)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How I can create a drop down list using select_tag "xyz", options_for_select or any way where on selecting any option from down list and hitting button will redirect me.

Any help??

```
<td> 
  <%= select_tag "options", options_for_select( 
                              [["Dashboard", 
                                "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s
                              ]] ) %>
</td> 
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick = "check_options()" >
```

if above code is right then all i need to write a javascript?? please let me now

```
function = check_options() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript or even jquery on the client side you could set the window.location based on the selected item in the drop down, after you click the button:

HTML: **This is how you set up your select list and a button**

```
<select id="options">
  <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</option>
  <option value="http://google.com/">Google</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="optionsbutton" value="Go" />
```

JavaScript: **This is how you wire up the button click to the window redirect**

```
var onButtonClick = function() {
    window.location.replace($("#options").val()) //<--- This gets the selected value
                                                 //     and redirects the window
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#optionsbutton").click(onButtonClick);  //<--- This hooks up the button click
                                               //     to do the onButtonClick function
});
```

See [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery) for more details.

### Update Using Provided Code

You'd just have to make your check_options function find the selected value and set the window location:

```
var check_options = function() {
  window.location.replace($(" [ use selector for select element ] ").val());
});
```

Comment: I am new to ruby and javascript, sorry if I don't understand properly. Here is the code <td> <%= select_tag "options", options_for_select( [["Dashboard", "/homes/"+registrar.enrollment_application.id.to_s]] ) %></td>

 <input type="button" value="Select" onclick = "check_options()" >

 if above code is right then all i need to write a javascript?? please let me now                                            function = check_options() {

Comment: You can put the details of your question in the question rather than in comments.  I copied your code here into the question, but you can do it yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

You should add javascript like this

```
function check_options() { 
  window.location = document.getElementById("options").value
}
```